# Is there a better way of calling these balls with different color, x and speed each time?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I started learning JavaScript a few weeks ago and I decided to try and make my first game from scratch, in the code below I am trying to make the game so the balls fall each time with different position, color and speed and after that there will be another ball that ill be able to move with my mouse and will try to dodge the balls, so my question is is there a better way than the one I did to spawn more balls , because if I want to spawn like 5-6 more the code will look so bad and I am sure there is a better way of doing that, I am still learning so if you can hit me with a simple solution and explain it.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = random(1, 801);
var x2 = random(1, 801);
var y = 10;
var y2 = 10;
var ballRadius = random(2, 51);
var ballRadius2 = random(2, 51);
var color = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
var color2 = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
var dy = random(1, 6);
var dy2 = random(1, 6);

function random(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function drawBall() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBall2() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x2, y2, ballRadius2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = color2;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
    drawBall();
    drawBall2();
    y += dy;
    y2 += dy2;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

I want to know methods to simplify my code so I know for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

The main changes I made are the addition of the function createBall, allowing the creation of multiple new balls per tick, and the removal of balls that are out of view. I tried to add comments to the new parts, if you have any questions, let me know!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const desiredNumberOfBalls = 10;
let i = 0;

let balls = []; // Track each individual ball
const viewLimit = canvas.height; // The vertical distance a ball has when leaving sight

// For now we create a static paddle
const paddle = {
  x: 200,
  y: viewLimit - 10,
  width: 50,
  height: 10,
}

// This is a very rough calculation based on https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2100319 by checking first the corners and then the top edge
paddle.hitsBall = function(ball) {
  let hit = false;
  if (ball.y + ball.radius >= paddle.y) {
    // the ball is at the same level as the paddle
    if (Math.sqrt((ball.x - paddle.x) ** 2 + (ball.y - paddle.y) ** 2) < ball.radius) {
      // the upper left part of the paddle touches the ball
      hit = true;
    } else if (Math.sqrt((ball.x - paddle.x - paddle.width) ** 2 + (ball.y - paddle.y) ** 2) < ball.radius) {
      // the upper right part of the paddle touches the ball
      hit = true;
    } else if (ball.x >= paddle.x && ball.x <= paddle.x + paddle.width) {
      // the top edge of the paddle touches the ball
      hit = true;
    }
  }
  if (hit) console.log("Hit!");
  return hit;
}

function createBall() {
  let ball = {
    id: i++,
    x: random(1, canvas.width),
    y: 10,
    radius: random(2, 51),
    color: "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16),
    speed: random(1, 6)
  };
  return ball;
}

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function drawBall(ball) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'darkred';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function clearView() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function draw() {
  clearView();

  // Move all existing balls by their designated speed
  balls.forEach((ball) => {
    ball.y += ball.speed;
  });

  // Implicitly delete all balls that have exited the viewport
  // by only retaining the balls that are still inside the viewport
  balls = balls.filter((ball) => ball.y <= viewLimit);

  // Implicitly delete all balls that touch the paddle
  // by only retaining the balls that don't
  balls = balls.filter((ball) => !paddle.hitsBall(ball));

  // Create newBallsPerTick new balls
  while (balls.length < desiredNumberOfBalls) {
    balls.push(createBall());
  }

  // Draw the paddle
  drawPaddle();

  // Draw the position of every ball - both the pre-existing ones
  // and the ones we just generated
  balls.forEach((ball) => {
    drawBall(ball);
  });
}
setInterval(draw, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canv" height="400" width="600"></canvas>
```